# Isolating a server from other hosts on the same subnet

Tags: linux, networking

I have a server that I want to not be able to communicate with or see any other servers on the same subnet for certain reasons, but I still need the HTTP server on it to be accessible for anyone (already opened 443 for ANYWHERE from the server)

TLDR, Anyone would be able to access the webserver (even outside of our network), but the server itself can't see any other servers on the same network. Is there a way to do this without creating another VLAN just for this server? Are ACL rules a good option in this case? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "see other servers on the network?" Do you mean explore them, for server to be unable to initiate outgoing http(s) requests or something else?

Comment: You won't be able to totally hide the system from the lsn and still have it answering requests - as it will be discoverable through its ARP entries. Depending on your needs you can structure this to limit ARP responses (to the router) and firewall it and have it on a different subnet - even without vlanning.

Comment: @davidgo As in, the server can't interact with the other servers - for example in the case of an SSRF, an attacker won't be able to use the initial server which has the web server running on to prob the other servers in the network.

Comment: This should be doable with (iptables) firewall rules. Do you use SSH on the LAN to admin the server? What are the name servers? Can restrictions be limited to specific ports (eg 80 & 443). I don't believecACLs are the tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ethernet device is eth0, and you could probably get away with something like the below (some of this may be redundant and this has not been tested, so probably needs a bit of tuning/debugging)

```
  # Because we are inserting chains into the beginning, this file is read in reverse order.  This means we don't need to worry about other rules, these will take priority.
  # Drop outgoing packets we don't specifically allow
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -j DROP 

  # Allow ourselves to make DNS requests and other outbound requsts.  You might want to add other stuff like SSH
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

  # Allow incoming requests to web server to be answered. The magic is because we are responding, so we use source port.
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

 # We may or may not need to specify we want other traffic to be dropped.
 # This is probably not required but will explicitly prevent outgoing requests on port 443 and 80 (because its dport we know they are outgoing rather then incoming)
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -J DROP
  /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -J DROP
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add Firewall rule to isolate this server from all other servers on this sub-net. Suppose you have sub-net

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.0
Network Address:    192.168.1.0
Usable Host IP Range:   192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
Broadcast Address:  192.168.1.255
Total Number of Hosts:  256
Number of Usable Hosts: 254
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
```

Your desire server let suppose is hosted over `192.168.1.7` and you want then it could not access all other host at same sub-net.I am supposing you have ip-tables for fire-wall

```
# Allow traffic locally on the server

iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

# Block all OTHER traffic that does not meet  condition above

 iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

If you are in AWS or some other Cloud solution then you can user there own firewall.

Comment: This fails to answer the requirement for external access.